# Datastore entities imported into Big query tables without id column but __key__.id

Tags: import, google-bigquery, export, google-cloud-datastore

We are using Datastore export feature for exporting datastore entities and importing them in Big Query table. It works perfectly fine.
The only problem is that the entities imported in big query tables do not have '**id**' column but '**__key__.id**'.

We are using a hack(which is unnecessary overhead) for now get '**id**' column generated by following query written to target table.

select  **key**.id As id ,*  from `projectId.datasetId.ImportedTable`

Actually, this transfer has be automated via cron jobs and there is no scope for such hack there. so wanted to check if there is any way that imported table by itself, expose ID column.
Can the way we generate entities and choose its Primary column strategy play any role here?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, when importing data to BigQuery from Datastore, BigQuery creates a [RECORD type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore#datastore_key_properties) for each entity unique key. As this is automated it can't be modified the way is it done.

Maybe a good possibility will be updating the entities to add an extra property and copy the ID so this way the column will be named ID instead of **key**.id once the import is done to BigQuery.

As this feature is not yet included in the export service between Datastore and BigQuery, you can create a Feature Request in Google Cloud Platform's [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).